# Wifi connection drops multiple times a day

Tags: windows, internet-connection

For the past two weeks my laptop started randomly disconnecting from the router, which is getting more annoying by the day. Here is a list of clues I found so far:

- **It is no hardware issue:** For two days I booted Linux from USB stick and connected with the exact same settings to the same router, worked on my projects as usual and didn't encounter any connection problems, so neither my laptop nor my router is broken.
- **List of events generated with each disconnect:** Everytime my laptop spontaneously disconnects I see the exact same events generated under `Windows-Protocols/System`:

  - Browser service, event ID 8033:

    > The browser has forced an election on network "\Device\NetBT_Tcpip_{GUID}" because a master browser was stopped.
  - Diagnostics-Networking, event ID 6100: This event is a long long check list, where every test is passed, but at the end it reads

    > Disconnected from BSSID: 00-00-00-00-00-00 Reason: 0x00000205
  - Diagnostics-Networking, event ID 6100:

    > The capability of your network adapter does not match the requirement of this network.

    This is funny, because in the previous event there are 3 lines saying that my network adapter's capability match the profile. My adapter worked for the past two years and I can't remember changing my network settings.
  - Diagnostics-Networking, event ID 4000:

    > The capability of your network adapter does not match the requirement of this network.
    >
    > Root cause GUID: "{a5d48b7a-6b63-449f-909d-c239efeb2463}"
    >
    > Repair GUID: "{86c9d24e-59ea-437a-9e39-6f7f212664fe}"
  - NETwNb64, event ID 8000, (7036), 7001, 7001:

    > No description found for event ID "...". Stored information:
    >
    > \Device\NDMP8
    >
    > Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260

    This is odd, because googling this event reveals that most people actually get an event description. Maybe my system misses a library containing this description?
- **It doesn't seem to be any windows update:** I uninstalled all windows updates of the last two months (way more than necessary) and yet the problem persists.
- **Strange behaviour:** To reconnect with my network I have to turn of my network adapter, turn it back on and then try two to five times to connect to my network until it works. For every failed trial all the events above are generated.

I'm out of ideas where to look for more clues. In case this might be useful, I appended some hardware information. Do you guys have any idea, what's might be wrong with my wifi connection?

- Windows 8.1 x64 with Kaspersky
- Network adapter: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
- Driver for network adapter: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 version 18.33.6.2 (19 Feb 2017)

Comment: According to the answers at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e3aff22a-3361-447e-af24-d412a2698214/wireless-connection-suddenly-dropping-with-windows-7-pro-64bit?forum=w7itpronetworking this appears to be a driver problem. Have you tried reinstalling your adapter drivers?

Comment: Since I rolled back my driver to the previous version about 4 hours ago, I hadn't had any issues (where I expected at least 2 disconnects), so I think it might actually be a driver issue. Kinda funny that the first time I didn't try a driver rollback (because so far drivers never were the cause for my problems) it actually was the driver. Thanks you :)

Comment: I have the same issue with Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165. I excatly know that is not a hardware problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author of this question has found out the the problem was due to their drivers, and did a driver rollback in order to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Changing the channel width from Auto to 20 MHz solved it for me.

In Device Manager, right click on "Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260" and select Properties, under Advance Tab, change Channel width to "20 MHz Only".

Answer (score 0):

I tried both rolling back my drivers and specifying 20 MHz channel width but neither worked in isolation. I had to both rollback and specify 20 MHz.